# Placing TabControl vertically

Tags: xaml, silverlight, controls, silverlight-3.0

How do I make a Silverlight `TabControl` arrange the tabs vertically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TabControl Formatting (Right Justified and Vertical Text)

```
<Controls2:TabControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TabStripPlacement="Left"></Controls2:TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have install the silverlight toolkit and then use the rotate layout to turn the tab header.

```
<UserControl xmlns:controls=”clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls” 
x:Class=”SilverlightApplication18.MainPage”
xmlns=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation“
xmlns:x=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml“
xmlns:toolkit=”clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit”            
Width=”400″ Height=”300″>
<Grid x:Name=”LayoutRoot” Background=”White”>
    <controls:TabControl Margin=”10″ TabStripPlacement=”Left”>
        <controls:TabItem  >
            <controls:TabItem.Header>
                <toolkit:LayoutTransformer >
                    <TextBlock Text=”Tab1″/>
                    <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle=”-90″></RotateTransform>
                    </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
            </controls:TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock  Margin=”10″ Text=”some content in Tab1″/>               
        </controls:TabItem>
```

The result will like:
[image: Vertical tab layout]!

May be I can't upload a picture, the result will like this, but all the text is rotated -90 in the real result.

```
+--+------------------------------
|l |
|a |
|c |
|i |
|t |
|r |
|e |
|v |
+--+
|
|
+--------------------------------
```

The relative article is [here](http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tabcontrol-and-vertical-text/)